# Select columns of specific type in MySQL 4.1

Tags: mysql

I need to find all smallint (specifically smallint(5)) columns in a MySQL 4.1 database. It seems that INFORMATION_SCHEMA is only available in MySQL 5+. Is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-columns.html) syntax to return the data you need.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of filtering the result eg. WHERE Type = 'x'

Comment: You can filter the results by the field name, but not by the type.  However, since you can pull the results of SHOW COLUMNS out as if it were a SELECT query, you can just filter out the results in your code.

Answer (score 17):

Here's something that should work for you:

```
select distinct table_name, column_name, column_type
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'THE_DB_YOU_WANT_TO_QUERY' 
    and column_type = 'smallint(5)';
```

Obviously, replace 'THE_DB_YOU_WANT_TO_QUERY' with the actual name of your database. It took me awhile to get all of this to work, but it should work for you.

Comment: The question mentions they are on MySQL 4.1 and that "It seems that INFORMATION_SCHEMA is only available in MySQL 5+" ... However, I think it's still helpful for people who get here via search who happen to be on MySQL 5

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work

`SHOW TABLES; # Get list of all tables

DESC [EACH TABLE]; # and then check "Type" column`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you could use the following functions to gain information about specific fields in your tables.

```
mysql_field_type
mysql_fetch_field
mysql_field_len
mysql_field_flags
```

mysql_fetch_field gives you the most info.

To give you an example of how you might use it:

```
$SQLquery = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tableName;
$arr;
$field_array = array();
$res = mysql_query($SQLquery);

$numOfCols = mysql_num_fields($res);

for($y=0;$y<=($numOfCols-1);$y++)
{
    $fieldName1 =  mysql_field_name($res, $y);
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($res, $y);
    if($field->max_length < 6 && $field->numeric = true)
    {
      $field_array[] = $fieldName1;
    }
}
```

I realize this is not a MySql answer but I hope it helps if there is no way to get the info you need via MySql in 4.1